# Request to https://bower.herokuapp.com/packages/ember-cli-test-loader failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I am new to ember.js.

While trying to get started in ember.js , it asked me install bower.

While doing $bower install i am getting the message.

bower ember-cli-test-loader#0.2.2SELF_SIGNED_CERT_IN_CHAIN Request to https://bower.herokuapp.com/packages/ember-cli-test-loader failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain

Please help me to resolve this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a .bowerrc file in your app's root directory and include the following JSON:

```
{
  "directory": "bower_components/",
  "registry":"http://bower.herokuapp.com"
}
```

This will use the non-ssl version of heroku's bower repository.

Answer (score 1):

Bower is deprecating their registry hosted with Heroku. http://bower.herokuapp.com/ Will not be accessible anymore or it might be down intermittently, therefore, forcing users to a new registry.

Users working on old bower versions can update the .bowerrc file with the following data.

```
{
  "registry": "https://registry.bower.io"
}
```

.bowerrc file can be located at the same folder where bower.json and bower_components folder is located. If it is not present already, you can make one.

For references check the below links

https://twitter.com/bower/status/918073147789889536
https://gist.github.com/sheerun/c04d856a7a368bad2896ff0c4958cb00

Comment: Thank you Rahul for adding the updated answer!  I just want to add that Bower itself is deprecated and Ember devs should use npm packages with npm auto import whenever they can.